# Detect is_base_of with base class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Given the code:

```
template<typename T, typename Other = SomeDefault>
struct Cat { ... };

template<typename T>
struct Bengal : Cat<T> { ... };

template<typename T>
struct Persian : Cat<T, Something> { ... };

struct Siberian : Cat<int> { ... };
```

How do I implement a trait `is_cat<T>` so that

- `is_cat<Cat<int, float>>`, `is_cat<Bengal<double>>`, `is_cat<Persian<std::string>>` and `is_cat<Siberian>` are `std::true_type`
- `is_cat<double>` (and for other unrelated types) is `std::false_type`

I think `std::is_base_of` is the right direction, but I don't know how I can make it work with unknown type parameters of the base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::is_base_of` doesn't help here, that only checks if a concrete base class is a base. But we're not looking for a concrete base, we're looking for a base class template. For that, we can take advantage of overload resolution:

```
std::false_type is_cat_impl(...);
template <typename T, typename U>
std::true_type is_cat_impl(Cat<T,U>*);

template <typename T>
using is_cat = decltype(is_cat_impl(std::declval<T*>()));
```

For something that's a `Cat<T,U>`, `Cat<T,U>*` is a better match than `...` For anything else, it's not a match at all.

---

If you want to also match `Siberian const&`, then, as Oliv suggests, it's better to use references instead of pointers:

```
std::false_type is_cat_impl(...);
template <typename T, typename U>
std::true_type is_cat_impl(Cat<T,U> const volatile&);

template <typename T>
using is_cat = decltype(is_cat_impl(std::declval<T&>()));
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I want `is_cat<const Siberian&>` to match as well, so I just write `std::declval<decay_t<T>*>()`, right?

Comment: @basteln You can do the same with references: ... `true_type is_cat_impl(const volatile Cat<T,U>&)` and `decltype(is_cat_impl(std::declval<T&>()));` will be less sensible to cv ref qualification.

Comment: Great! Thank you guys.